# How do I tell if a prop was passed in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react function component, This function takes in some props.

I want to know if the component had a specific prop passed to it.

Say I have a component, Song, that takes in 1 prop, Genre. I would want to know if the component when used was used with the genre prop.

examples:

- genre not passed:

```js
<Song></Song>
```

- genre passed:

```js
<Song genre="Rap"></Song>
```

edit: clarity

Comment: Do you mean no description at all, or a description property that's an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for the `undefined` value for the description.

for example:

```
const MyComponent = ({ title, description }) => {
    return (
        <div class ="card">
            <div class="card-header">{title}</div>
            {description && <div class="card-body">{description}</div>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In above example I have used conditional rendering to meet your requirement.

Comment: This works also, prefer this over mine since its shorter.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must create the functional compontent that receive props from parent `genre` and the default props of `genre` is all, maybe the component will look like this:

```
const Song = ({ genre="all" }) => {
   if(genre === "all") {
     return(
        <div>this song list has a all genre</div>
     )
   } else if(genre === "Rap") {
     return(
        <div>this song list has a genre {genre}</div>
     )
   }
}
```

if we set default props so when from the parent component did not send props `genre` the default props of genre in `song` (which is "all") component will be applied.